# env variables does not change in .next folder nextjs production

Tags: node.js, next.js

I build a full-stack app using Netxjs, I create a build from it and uploaded `.next` folder on the Cpanel. I create a node app:

my node app console screenshot:
[image]

I added env variables in node env variables and `next.config.js`:

`next.config.js` Code :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  env: {
    dbName: "my_databaseName",
    dbUserName: "my_databaseName",
    dbPassword: "my_databasepassword",
    dbHost: "localhost",
    baseUrl: "https://my-website.com",
    NEXTAUTH_URL: "https://my-website.com",
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

but in log file I got error: `FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/home reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

and when I check `.next/server/pages/index.js` file inside `getServerSideProps` function:

```
const response = await fetch(`${"http:localhost:3000"}/api/home`);
```

but it should be:

```
const response = await fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}/api/home`);
```

and because of this I got 500 error on the page I have HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use `.env` file instead of adding vars in `next config` file.

Second, when you want to deploy a next app, you must `ignore` these folders and files, then you must build your app on the host.

`.next` `node_modules` `package-lock.json` `.env.local`

Uploading `.next` folder will take a long time, also it may crash your app.